# How to make tap click faster?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, magic-trackpad, click

The response of simple tap click on track pad is incredibly slow (like 1 s), (meanwhile usual click seems to be faster). 
Same for "right button"-click - tap with two fingers.
How can I speed up the tapping response?

Comment: What device does your question relate to?

Comment: Track pad. Sorry.

Comment: You mean Apple's Magic Trackpad (http://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/)? Do you have this issue regularly or it just happened now?

Comment: jaume, Not exactly, I have macbook. Same with remote magic trackpad and iMac. I guess regularly, before I did try to play games and this wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
Go to **System Preference > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options** and disable dragging

Answer (score 0):

## No.

Unfortunately, the tap-to-click functionality on both MacBook trackpads and Magic trackpads can not be adjusted at the present - that might change in a future release (hopefully?).

### Here's why:

When tap-to-click functionality is enabled, there are two things it is watching for:

- A single tap (single click)
- A double tap (double click)

When a single tap is detected, the system doesn't know if you are intending to just make a single click or tap *again* for a double click - hence the 'delay' experienced.

Comment: Yes. But thereis no double tap with 2 fingers. And I have increased the speed of double tap - it changes nothing.

Comment: One more - double click exist for a usual mouse as well :) a usual mouse doesn't has such a problem.

Comment: @klm You can double-click faster with a 'usual' mouse